# Update counter in DB using JPA, avoiding manual synchronization

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data

I have a Counter entity as below : for each prefix (current year and month), I am maintaining a counter that I need to increment.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_COUNTER")
@SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, name = "S_COUNTER", sequenceName = "S_COUNTER")
public class CodeCounter implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 6431190800245592165L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "S_COUNTER")
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "PREFIX", nullable = false,unique = true)
private String prefix;

@Column(name = "COUNTER", nullable = false)
private Integer counter;
```

This is my very simple JPA repository, using Spring data :

```
public interface CodeCounterRepository extends JpaRepository<CodeCounter, Long> {

@Transactional
CodeCounter findByPrefix(String prefix);

}
```

Now, whenever my service is called, I need to get the right counter thanks to the prefix (and create it if it doesn't exist yet, the first time of the month), increment and save back. This is how I have implemented it so far :

```
//entry point in the service
public String generateUniqueRequestCode() {
    System.out.println("Generating new Request Code for Consolidated Request");

    Integer counter = getUniqueCodeAndUpdateCounter(calendarProvider);
    String requestCode = format("%s_%04d_%02d_%06d", REQUEST_CODE_PREFIX, calendarProvider.getCurrentYear(), calendarProvider.getCurrentMonth(),
            counter);

    System.out.println("New Request Code for Consolidated Request:: " + requestCode);

    return requestCode;
}

@Transactional
private synchronized Integer getUniqueCodeAndUpdateCounter(CalendarProvider calendarProvider) {

    System.out.println("entering..");

    String prefix = format("%04d_%02d", calendarProvider.getCurrentYear(), calendarProvider.getCurrentMonth());

    CodeCounter codeCounter = codeCounterRepository.findByPrefix(prefix);
    if (codeCounter != null) {
        codeCounter.setCounter(codeCounter.getCounter() + 1);
    } else {
        codeCounter = new CodeCounter();
        codeCounter.setPrefix(prefix);
        codeCounter.setCounter(1);
    }

    CodeCounter counter=codeCounterRepository.save(codeCounter);
    int result=counter.getCounter();

    System.out.println("..exiting");

    return result;
}
```

I've added a multithreaded unit test (using tempus fugit library ) with H2 DB, that shows it's working when 2 threads try to generate a unique code at the same time, but I'm not too happy with my code : **I would like to get rid of that `synchronized` method and rely solely on proper transaction configuration.**

If I remove the `synchronized` keyword, then both threads execute the method at same time and it fails because they generate the same prefix, which shouldn't happen (Unique index or primary key violation). Here's the log :

> Generating new Request Code for Consolidated Request
>
> Generating new Request Code for Consolidated Request
>
> entering..
>
> entering..
>
> Hibernate: select codecounte0_.id as id1_4_, codecounte0_.counter as counter2_4_, codecounte0_.prefix as prefix3_4_ from t_counter codecounte0_ where codecounte0_.prefix=?
>
> Hibernate: select codecounte0_.id as id1_4_, codecounte0_.counter as counter2_4_, codecounte0_.prefix as prefix3_4_ from t_counter codecounte0_ where codecounte0_.prefix=?
>
> Hibernate: call next value for S_COUNTER Hibernate: call next value for S_COUNTER
>
> Hibernate: insert into t_counter (counter, prefix, id) values (?, ?, ?)
>
> Hibernate: insert into t_counter (counter, prefix, id) values (?, ?, ?)
>
> ..exiting
>
> New Request Code for Consolidated Request:: CR_2016_09_000001
>
> 17:02:39.853 WARN  SqlExceptionHelper        - SQL Error: 23505, SQLState: 23505
>
> 17:02:39.854 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper - Unique index or primary key violation...

Any idea of how to implement this without synchronizing myself in the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Is writing a method in your entity that is annotated with **@PrePersist** or **@PreUpdate** something that you are looking for?

Comment: I am not sure what I could do in @PrePersist to make sure the second thread "waits" for the operation to be flushed and visible, so that it sees the record exists and doesn't try to create a second one with same prefix.